# How do I add a java gradle project on my file system as a dependency to another local project?

Tags: java, gradle

I have project2 that depends on project1. They are both next to each other on my file system.

When I try to build project2 (after successfully building project1) I get the error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:distTar'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :project1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :project1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Project2 adds the dependency to project1 as follows...

build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'

    implementation project(':project1')
    implementation files('../../project1/lib/build/libs/lib.jar')
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'project2.App'
}
```

Settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'project2'
include('app')

include   ':project1'
project(':project1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../project1')
```

The source for project1...

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package project1;

public class Library {
    public boolean someLibraryMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The source for project2

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package project2;

import project1.*;

public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
        bool someBool = Library.someLibraryMethod();
    }
}
```

the complete folder structure of the two projects. Although it looks like project2 is under project1, that is just how the copy pasted output looks, they are indeed sibling folders.

```
── project1
│   ├── gradle
│   │   └── wrapper
│   │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│   │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   │   ├── main
│   │   │   │   └── project1
│   │   │   │       └── Library.class
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   │       └── project1
│   │   │           └── LibraryTest.class
│   │   ├── build

│   │   │   ├── libs
│   │   │   │   └── lib.jar

│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   └── src
│   │       ├── main
│   │       │   ├── java
│   │       │   │   └── project1
│   │       │   │       └── Library.java
│   │       │   └── resources
│   │       └── test
│   │           ├── java
│   │           │   └── project1
│   │           │       └── LibraryTest.java
│   │           └── resources
│   └── settings.gradle
└── project2
    ├── app
    │   ├── build.gradle
    │   └── src
    │       ├── main
    │       │   ├── java
    │       │   │   └── project2
    │       │   │       └── App.java
    │       │   └── resources
    │       └── test
    │           ├── java
    │           │   └── project2
    │           │       └── AppTest.java
    │           └── resources
    ├── gradle
    │   └── wrapper
    │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
    │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
    ├── gradlew
    ├── gradlew.bat
    └── settings.gradle
```

69 directories, 37 files

Comment: From what I can tell from your directory structure, project 2 is nested under project 1, yet it has its own `settings.gradle` file. Is project 2 supposed to be a sub-project? Or did you mean them to be two separate projects?

Comment: @Slaw that is just some graphical confusion from the tree output. project1 and project2 are sibling directories at the same level.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. Perhaps this is what you're looking for: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using? That could help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to include the project1 in two ways: first, as a project dependency, and second, as a JAR file. Remove the line `implementation files('../../project1/lib/build/libs/lib.jar')` from your build.gradle file and only keep the project dependency `implementation project(':project1')`. Also, check the path specified in settings.gradle file, if the path is correct and the project1 folder exist in that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Types of Builds

First you have to decide if this should be a [multi-project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) or a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#defining_composite_builds).

### Multi-Project Build

This is when you have a single Gradle project that is made up of multiple sub-projects. You should use a multi-project build if the various modules are highly coupled.

You create a sub-project by using `include` in the `settings.gradle[.kts]` file. But you should only have the one settings file. Each individual sub-project may have its own `build.gradle[.kts]` file, and typically does, but does not necessarily have to. There are various ways to cross-configure sub-projects. See the documentation linked above for details.

I do not provide an example of a multi-project build in this answer.

### Composite Build

This is when you have two (or more?) relatively independent projects, but one depends on the other like any other external dependency. Yet you want to use the artifacts of the Gradle project directly rather than grab the binaries from a repository. At least some of the time, anyway.

There are a few ways to create a composite build.

1. Use `--include-build` on the command line. This requires the least amount of modification to either project (none).
2. Use `includeBuild` in the `settings.gradle[.kts]` file (**not** `include`, as that's for multi-project builds). This requires modifying at least one of the project's configurations, which may not be desirable.
3. Create a "parent" Gradle project for the "real" projects with a `settings.gradle[.kts]` file. Then add `includeBuild` for the "real" projects that you want to composite.

In a composite build, the way dependencies are resolved is described in the documentation linked above. Here's an excerpt:

> Included builds interact with other builds via [*dependency substitution*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sec:dependency_substitution_rules). If any build in the composite has a dependency that can be satisfied by the included build, then that dependency will be replaced by a project dependency on the included build. *Because of the reliance on dependency substitution, composite builds may force configurations to be resolved earlier, when composing the task execution graph. This can have a negative impact on overall build performance, because these configurations are not resolved in parallel*.

Note you don't use `project("...")` to define a dependency on an included build. You simply use the regular Maven coordinates like normal, and if the included build has a project matching those coordinates, then it will be substituted in.

---

## Example Composite Build

This example uses `--include-build` to create a composite build. Although this example can be reproduced by following the instructions below, it can be a little error-prone and tedious, so here is a [GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/stack-overflow1/so-75045567) of the final example. I make no promise to keep the repository alive.

### Source Code

Here is how the two projects were generated and any changes I made to the build configurations and or the code. Note I used Gradle 7.6 when running the `init` task. Also, when prompted with:

> ```
> Generate build using new APIs and behavior (some features may change in the next minor release)? (default: no) [yes, no]
> ```

I answered, "no".

#### Project 1

This project is the "library". It was generated with the following command:

```
...\demo\project1> gradle init --type java-library --test-framework junit-jupiter --project-name project1 --package sample.project1 --dsl kotlin
```

I only made modifications to the following files:

**lib\build.gradle.kts**

I added:

```kotlin
group = "sample.project1"
version = "1.0"
```

**lib\src\main\java\sample\project1\Library.java**

Changed it to:

```java
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package sample.project1;

public class Library {

    public static void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Hello, this is a composite build!");
    }
}
```

**lib\src\test\java\sample\project1\LibraryTest.java**

I deleted this file.

#### Project 2

This project is the "application". It depends on project 1. It was generated with the following command:

```
...\demo\project2> gradle init --type java-application --test-framework junit-jupiter --project-name project2 --package sample.project2 --dsl kotlin
```

I only made modifications to the following files:

**app\build.gradle.kts**

I added:

```kotlin
group = "sample.project2"
version = "1.0"
```

And added the following to the `dependencies` block:

```kotlin
// ADD DEPENDENCY ON PROJECT 1
implementation("sample.project1:lib:1.0")
```

**app\src\main\java\sample\project2\App.java**

I changed it to:

```java
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package sample.project2;

import sample.project1.Library;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Library.printMessage();
    }
}
```

**app\src\test\java\sample\project2\AppTest.java**

I deleted this file.

### Directory Structure

Here is the directory structure of the two projects after generating them and making the above modifications. The output excludes the `.gradle` directory.

```
...\DEMO
├───project1
│   │   .gitattributes
│   │   .gitignore
│   │   gradlew
│   │   gradlew.bat
│   │   settings.gradle.kts
│   │
│   ├───gradle
│   │   └───wrapper
│   │           gradle-wrapper.jar
│   │           gradle-wrapper.properties
│   │
│   └───lib
│       │   build.gradle.kts
│       │
│       └───src
│           ├───main
│           │   ├───java
│           │   │   └───sample
│           │   │       └───project1
│           │   │               Library.java
│           │   │
│           │   └───resources
│           └───test
│               ├───java
│               └───resources
└───project2
    │   .gitattributes
    │   .gitignore
    │   gradlew
    │   gradlew.bat
    │   settings.gradle.kts
    │
    ├───app
    │   │   build.gradle.kts
    │   │
    │   └───src
    │       ├───main
    │       │   ├───java
    │       │   │   └───sample
    │       │   │       └───project2
    │       │   │               App.java
    │       │   │
    │       │   └───resources
    │       └───test
    │           ├───java
    │           └───resources
    └───gradle
        └───wrapper
                gradle-wrapper.jar
                gradle-wrapper.properties
```

### Running Example

Running the example with the following command:

```
...\demo\project2> .\gradlew app:run --include-build ..\project1 --console plain
```

<sup>**Note:** I used `--console plain` in order to see all the task output. That way you can see tasks from the included build were executed. You do not need to include this option if you don't want to.</sup>

Gave the following output:

```
> Task :app:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :project1:lib:compileJava
> Task :project1:lib:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :project1:lib:classes
> Task :project1:lib:jar
> Task :app:compileJava
> Task :app:classes

> Task :app:run
Hello, this is a composite build!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

Comment: When I run the command 'gradle init --type java-library' it creates my build.gradle in a sub-folder called 'lib'. What implications does this have for this example? Could you update the example to have project1 as a lib generate by 'gradle init --type java-library'. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, in my initial post, project2 is dependant on project1...I think you have got those mixed up, which could confuse people.

Comment: @Scorb I edited my answer and made the example more like the projects in your question.

Comment: @Scorb And by the way, the artifact coordinates are, by default `<group>:<project-name>:<version>`, if I'm not mistaken. The `init` task seems to have changed in recent years, or more specifically, the recommended project organization has changed. Now it seems they recommend having a sub-project even in an effectively single-project build. Most likely to have the source code in e.g., `lib` rather than in the root directory. So, for instance, `gradle init --type java-library` includes a sub-project named `lib`. Meaning the coordinates are `<group>:lib:<version>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make directories `project1` and `project2` both modules, one application and one library module.
Files `gradle`, `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat`, `settings.gradle` need to be moved one level up. The root project needs it's own `build.gradle`. Including
the modules in `settings.gradle` is straightforward:

```
include ':project1'
include ':project2'
```

Then one can depend on module `:project2` in module `:project1`:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation project(':project2')
    api project(':project2')
}
```

The library could also be published to the default local repository `mavenLocal()`. Unless publishing a sources package to Maven (eg. `lib-sources.jar`), it's usually easier to debug with two modules. The library module still can be made a Git sub-module.